# Can't start mysqld after installing MySQL 5.6 in EC2 running Redhat 6.5

Tags: amazon-ec2, mysql

From Amazon EC2 instance, I have removed the default MySQL 5.1 and installed MySQL 5.6 following the instructions from:

http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/12/26/install-mysql-server-5-6-in-centos-6-x-and-red-hat-6-x-linux/

Although it is installed, can't start mysqld, here is the log file:

```
140112 23:16:53 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2014-01-12 23:16:54 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [ERROR] InnoDB: auto-extending data file ./ibdata1 is of a different size 640 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file: initial 768 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Binlog end
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-01-12 23:16:54 7601 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

What's the step to solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Try adding this to my.cnf:

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
```

That should fix the issue

Comment: Thank you! that solves my problem. but, just wonder...why? The error says something wrong with the dbstructure I guess, but the configuration you used literarily extends the innodb capacity I guess. don't feel weel when feel lost...

Answer (score 5):

Reinstalling MySQL may fix the problem.

```
yum remove -y mysql mysql-server
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
yum install mysql mysql-server
service mysqld start
```

Comment: this is a cleaner solution for me, it works as well.

Comment: straight forward solution, but it's self-explanatory (and really works)

Answer (score 0):

As you said,mysql 5.1 is removed and have installed new mysql version.
The problem seems to be in my.cnf file. check the innodb related parameters.Might the my.cnf file is still has MySQL 5.1 parameters.

Regards
Sharad